# Show specific logo for user group in Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla

I can't seem to see a logical way to do this, I've tried many different functions, some of which i get blank page errors, other which it seems to work but just skips and goes to the else function everytime.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to have it so that certain logos will be displayed depending on the User Group ID.

At the moment the code below is producing a blank error page, and I can't see why.

Could anyone help me with this? Joomla 3.1 by the way.

```
<?php $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $usergroup=$user->getAuthorisedGroups();
    if ($usergroup == '10') : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>" id="gkLogo">
            <img src="/images/fordlogo.png" alt="<?php echo $this->API->getPageName(); ?>" />
        </a>
    <?php elseif ($usergroup == '7') : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>" id="gkLogo">
            <img src="/images/tescologo.png" alt="<?php echo $this->API->getPageName(); ?>" />
        </a>
    <?php else; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>" id="gkLogo">
            <img src="<?php echo $logo_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->API->getPageName(); ?>" />
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$usergroup = $user->getAuthorisedGroups();

if(in_array('10',$usergroup)){
    echo '<a href="'.JURI::root().'" id="gkLogo">
            <img src="/images/fordlogo.png" alt="'.$this->API->getPageName().'" />
          </a>';
}elseif(in_array('7',$usergroup)){
    echo '<a href="'.JURI::root().'" id="gkLogo">
            <img src="/images/fordlogo.png" alt="'.$this->API->getPageName().'" />
          </a>';    
}else{
    echo '<a href="'.JURI::root().'" id="gkLogo">
            <img src="/images/fordlogo.png" alt="'.$this->API->getPageName().'" />
          </a>';    
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: how can i insert the image html tags within the php code? DOn't I have to put it in "" ?

Comment: it still produces a white blank screen

Comment: @LeeCollings See my updated answer. For error you need to check by enable the error reporting on `php.ini` or top of the `index.php` or `.htaccess` for checking if you have any syntax error on the code or any other error.

Comment: In Joomla you set the error reporting in global config.
Where are you putting this code?

Comment: Thanks for this help, I did manage to get it working in the end. But I can't remember if it was because of the above, so for now I Can't mark it as the accepted answer, sorry.